Equivalent formulations of strict positivity of a symmetric operator
Suppose $\mathcal{H}$ is a separable Hilbert space, and $A: \mathcal{H} \mapsto \mathcal{H}$ is a symmetric linear operator. We say $A$ is a strictly positive definite operator if $\langle Ax, x \rangle > 0$ for all $x \ne 0$. What are some other equivalent formulations? For example, in the finite dimensional case if we can write $A= R R^\top$ for a square matrix $R$ that is full rank, this is sufficient. Are there any analogous conditions to this?

Nearly the same holds. In the complex case, $A$ is strictly positive iff $A = RR^\ast$ for some $R: \mathcal{H} \to \mathcal{H}$ with dense range. Pretty sure the same holds for symmetric $A$ on a real Hilbert space as well.

The operator $A$ is strictly positive iff it is positive and injective. Equivalently $A=R^*R,$ where $R$ is injective.
